# eventhandling and react with node & express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to learn react, so I have a very noobish question.

I'm trying to figure out how the event handling works.
My code:

```js
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var reactViews = require('express-react-views');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', reactViews.createEngine());

var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/', routes.index);
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

// routes/index.js
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { name: 'John', occupation:"Driver", age: 22 });
};

//views/layouts/default.jsx
var React = require('react');
class DefaultLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <head><title>{this.props.title}</title></head>
        <body>{this.props.children}</body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = DefaultLayout;
```

Rendering part:
I've been trying a couple of different things. Mostly trying to get jquery to work(Worked with it before, so it's familliar) and getting to log to client console.
What I think my problem is, this is all rendered serverside so the scripts are not embedded(right word?). So I guess the content has to be rendered dynamically, but how do I do that?

```jsx
//views/index.jsx
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().defaultView);

function countTo(n:number):string {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    a.push(i + 1);
  }
  console.log("Hello wef")
  return a.join(', ');
}
$("#main").on("click", "#testbtn", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    console.log("Button clicked");
})

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
logCmd(){
    console.log("Hello world");
}
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
}
// handleClick: (e) => {
//  e.preventDefault();
//  console.log("The link was clicked.");
// }

  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
       <div id="main">Hello {this.props.name} <br />
            Occupation {this.props.occupation} <br />

            Age of {this.props.name} is {this.props.age} <br />
            <form id="myForm">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Kakespade" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onChange={this.logCmd()} />
            </form>

            <input id="testbtn" type="button" value="Test" onChange={this.logCmd()} />
            <a id="testlink" href="#" onChange={this.handleClick}>
                Click me
            </a>
            <p>
                I can count to 10:
                {countTo(10)}
            </p>
        </div>
      </DefaultLayout>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = HelloMessage;
```

To make it render dynamically I guess I have to change some stuff in my app.js file. Where can I find information on how to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to use jquery with react - that makes no sense...

Comment: I could not get it working with the logCmd() or handleClick functions so I tried with jquery

Answer (score 0):

you have such code in //views/index.jsx:

```
<a id="testlink" href="#" onChange={this.handleClick}>
  Click me
</a>
```

Maybe you wanted to do

```
<a id="testlink" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
  Click me
</a>
```

*(onChange -> onClick)*

in the rest of this part of the code looks Ok

Comment: If you just started learning React maybe it would be easier to start with pure React in browser? I mean something like [react-storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/react-storybook) you could exclude all about backside

Comment: I've tried with both onClick and onChange, but the console.log does not fire when I click the button, only when I load the page

Comment: I suppose you have such behavior because of server side stuff. Sorry cant dig in it for now. Maybe you'll find interesting something like `nextJS` for serverside rendering